# Extending nested class from abstract class in a subclass and making the methods use the new definition of the nested class

Tags: java, abstract-class, nested-class

I have a base abstract class with a nested class inside of it. In one of the subclasses I need to extend the nested class, but the abstract methods inherited from the base class expect the base class definition of the nested class (for return types and arguments). How can I make them use the new definition of the nested class?
Also the nonabstract methods(which I'm not overriding) don't work properly either(and they worked fine before I moved them to the abstract class).

```
abstract class Base {
    protected class Nested{
        ....
    }
    protected abstract Nested someMethod();
    protected void anotherMethod(Nested x){
        ......
    }
}
class Derived {
    class Nested extends Base.Nested {
        ....
    }
    protected Nested someMethod() {
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best route would be to declare a `protected`, optionally abstract factory method to create the `Nested` class.

Something like this:

```
abstract class Base {
    protected class BaseNested {
        ....
    }
    protected abstract BaseNested newNested();
}

class Derived extends Base {
    class DerivedNested extends BaseNested {
        ....
    }

    protected BaseNested newNested() {
       return new DerivedNested();
    }
}
```

Then when your base class wants a new `BaseNested`, it calls `newNested` instead of `new DerivedNested()`.

If for some reason you need `Derived` to only deal with `Derived.Nested` for those methods, and not `Base.Nested` (you should carefully evaluate that decision) then you can use generics.  Type `Base` on the type of nested class it deals with:

```
abstract class Base<T extends BaseNested> {
    protected abstract T newNested();
    protected abstract T someMethod();
    protected void anotherMethod(T nested) {
        //...
    }
}

class Derived extends Base<DerivedNested> {
    protected DerivedNested newNested() {
       return new DerivedNested();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Well, I couldn't get it to work, so I'm dropping the whole idea and I'll try something simpler. Thanks for the answer, though :)